# 'socket.http' DLLs aren't found when Lua is compiled

Tags: lua

I've started to really get into using Lua, and a few months ago I've figured out on how to turn .lua files into executables.

It's been working great so far, until I started to compile lua scripts that use 'socket.http'. It seems to be missing some DLLs of some sort, and I don't know how I would be able to add them into the same folder.

[image: The errors found]

Where would I find these such DLLs to add into the same folder of my executable, so that I could be able to run Lua executables using socket.http?

Answer (score 1):

`socket.http` module doesn't come as DLL; it comes as a pure-lua module. Usually there is `socket.lua` and `socket\http.lua` files (as well as `socket\core.dll`), so you'd need to package all of them and make them available to your script to make it work.

You can find the Lua files in the [luasocket repository](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/tree/master/src), but make sure that they match the API for the binaries (socket/core.* files) you are using.